# Obtaining areas from overlapping polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon-creation, overlapping-features, parcel, basic-license-level

Using ArcView 9.
I have a data set of about ten thousand parcel polygons and a similar number of driveway polygons extending from a roadway polygon into the parcel polygons. My ultimate goal is to get the driveway area within each parcel. 
Ideally this could be done through the creation of a new shapefile so that I can have a concise plan for each parcel, but any method that works is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use the [Interesct tool](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=intersect_%28analysis%29). This will output a new SHP file of driveways that overlap your land parcels along with the attributes of both datasets.

[image: Intersect example]

You can then add a new field to this outout dataset and calculate the geometry of each polygon to give you the area of driveway. Assuming each land parcel has a unique ID you can then  join this intersect area back to your original Parcel dataset then allowing you to work out how much of each land parcel is driveway.

Comment: Is this possible in Arcview? I can't find the tool.
Thanks.

Comment: It should be, have you used the search bar to look for it? Alternatively in the toolboxes menu try Analysis Tools > Overlay > Intersect